# Android file picker returns incorrect name in URI

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I am using the android file picker to select multiple files from external storage, but the Uri I'm getting doesn't have the correct name, it's like `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A2`
`image%3A25` is not the correct name of the file and it is also missing the extension.

Following is my code:

```
val selectFilesActivityResult =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->

                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    val data: Intent? = result.data

                    //If multiple files selected
                    if (data?.clipData != null) {
                        val count = data.clipData?.itemCount ?: 0

                        for (i in 0 until count) {
                            fileUtils.importFile(
                                data.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri!!,
                                viewModel.getInternalPath()
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    //If single file selected
                    else if (data?.data != null) {
                        fileUtils.importFile(
                            data.data!!,
                            viewModel.getInternalPath()
                        )

                    }
                }
            }
```

the file picker intent

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
                    intent.type = "*/*"
                    selectFilesActivityResult.launch(intent)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried changing the `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` but it didn't work.

Comment: Use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to wrap the `Uri` that you got back, then call `getName()` on the resulting `DocumentFile` to get a display name for the content that the user chose.

Answer (score 0):

That number has nothing to do with a file name or extension or file path.

There is no name in that uri and its not needed too.

It is just an index for the content provider to use in its database to get the right file when you ask for it.

To get the name of the file -inclusive extension- you just have to query() that content provider for DISPLAY_NAME for the uri.